# MOQ'd object returning null despite specifying .Returns

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unit-testing, moq

I am currently working with Moq to do some unit testing. I am running into an issue where I am specifying what my mocked object returns, but the actual call is returning null instead of what I am specifying in `.Returns(...)`. I've reviewed other posts and one of the suggestions was to create the mock with `MockBehavior.Strict`- after doing this, I get a fairly verbose error as follows:

`IMyRepository.Save(MvcIndividualAuth.Data.Models.DTO.MyTableDTO) invocation failed with mock behavior Strict.
All invocations on the mock must have a corresponding setup.`

However, I am calling setup on the only method that my mocked object calls already. Please see code below:

My test:

```
    MyService _myService;
    Mock<IMyRepository> _myRepoMock;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
      _myRepoMock = new Mock<IMyRepository>();
      _myService = new MyService(_myRepoMock.Object);
    }

[TestMethod]
    public void MyServiceSave()
    {
      //Arrange
      var myDto = new MyTableDTO { Id = 1, Bar = 5, Foo = "Test" };
      _myRepoMock.Setup(x => x.Save(myDto)).Returns(myDto);

      //Act
      var vm = _myService.Save(new MyTableViewModel(myDto));

      //Assert
      Assert.AreEqual(vm.Id, 1);
      Assert.AreEqual(vm.Foo, "Test");
      Assert.AreEqual(vm.Bar, 5);
      Assert.AreEqual(vm.BarPlusFoo, "5 Test");
    }
```

MyService.Save method:

```
    public MyTableViewModel Save(MyTableViewModel viewModel)
    {
      var dto = MyTableViewModel.GetDto(viewModel);
      var dbDto = _myRepo.Save(dto);    //_myRepo is of type IMyRepository, 
                                        // this _myRepo.Save call is returning null

      var vm = new MyTableViewModel(dbDto);

      return vm;
    }
```

Why is the mocked repo in my test not returning the value I specify in my `.Returns(..)` call? All help is appreciated.

EDIT: as requested, here is MyRepository.Save method and MyTableViewModel.GetDto():

MyRepository.Save:

```
public MyTableDTO Save(MyTableDTO dto)
    {
      try
      {
        var entity = new MyTable();

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dto.Foo))
        {
          throw new ArgumentException("MyTable requires Foo");
        }

        if (dto.Id == 0)
        {
          //added
          entity.Update(dto);
          _db.MyTables.Add(entity);
        }
        else
        {
          //modified
          entity = _db.MyTables.Single(x => x.Id == dto.Id);

          entity.Update(dto);
        }

        _db.SaveChanges();

        return new MyTableDTO(entity);
      }
      catch (Exception)
      {
        throw;
      }
    }
```

MyTableViewModel.GetDto(..);

```
public static MyTableDTO GetDto(MyTableViewModel vm)
    {
      var dto =  new MyTableDTO
      {
        Bar = vm.Bar,
        Foo = vm.Foo,
        Id = vm.Id
      };

      return dto;
    }
```

Comment: Could you show `Repository.Save()` method?

Comment: Please include the source code for `GetDto`.

Comment: @RomaDoskoch updated to show the requested

Comment: @mjwills updated to show the requested

Comment: It appears that the `myDto` object you use for the setup isn't the same one that's actually used in the test as that gets created by `GetDto`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get `null` because `GetDto()` returns object different from `myDto` - references are different.

You can change your `Setup()` to return `myDto`:

```
_myRepoMock.Setup(x => x.Save(It.IsAny<MyTableDTO>())).Returns(myDto);
```

Or if you want to return object which was passed as a parameter:

```
_myRepoMock.Setup(x => x.Save(It.IsAny<MyTableDTO>())).Returns((MyTableDTO dto) => dto);
```

Or if you want to mock based on some properties:

```
_myRepoMock.Setup(x => x.Save(It.Is<MyTableDTO>(dto => dto.Id == 1))).Returns(myDto);
```

Or if you want to modify return result:

```
_myRepoMock.Setup(x => x.Save(It.IsAny<MyTableDTO>())).Returns((MyTableDTO dto) => { dto.Id = 2; return dto;});
```

You can also combine all approaches.

Answer (score 3):

The `MyTableDTO` returned by `GetDTO` is a new `MyTableDTO` which is not the same as the rule in your `Setup`, because it has a different reference, hence there is no matching setup for `Save`.

Instead you can try something like:

```
_myRepo.Setup(s => s.Save(It.Is<MyTableDTO>(d => d.Equals(myDto))).Returns(myDto);
```

Or, if you are not concerned about the exact values passed to `Save`:

```
_myRepo.Setup(s => s.Save(It.IsAny<MyTableDTO>()).Returns(myDto);
```